# How to use property mediator pattern in wso2

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

When using property mediator pattern i am getting internal server error

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="regex">
  <log level="custom">
  <property name="log" value="******************************"/>
  </log>
  <property name="regex" expression="$url:regex" scope="default" 
   type="string" pattern="(.|\s)*\S(.|\s)*" group="2"/>
  <property name="service_ep"
    value="http://www.mocky.io/v2/5d0086223200007700f9d561" />
  <header name="To" expression="get-property('service_ep')" />
  <log level="full"/>
  </sequence>
```

Response what i am getting :

```
  <am:fault xmlns:am="http://wso2.org/apimanager">
  <am:code>0</am:code>
  <am:type>Status report</am:type>
  <am:message>Runtime Error</am:message>
  <am:description>Unknown type : string for the property mediator or the 
  property value cannot be converted into the specified type. 
  </am:description>
  </am:fault>
```

Comment: Can you provide more information in this matter? What is the URL you are calling? What is the message body? etc.

Comment: There is no message body. i just tried to examine how the pattern in property mediator works.For checking purpose only i am calling the mocky  url. what i am trying to do is validate the property (regex).but i dont know how the pattern works.

Answer (score 0):

The type should be in block letters.

```
<property name="regex" expression="$url:regex" scope="default" 
   type="STRING" pattern="(.|\s)*\S(.|\s)*" group="2"/>
```

Please refer to this documentation. https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI650/Property+Mediator#PropertyMediator-ConfigurationConfigs

Comment: Can you explain me how the pattern works and use of groups  and also i want know what happen if the value doesnt match with pattern.so what will be value of that property while error scenerios

Comment: The concept of pattern and group comes from Java regex library. Pattern and group are arguments that we pass to the java functions. If you want more explanation on this, you can search for java regex examples. A sample : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javaregex/javaregex_capturing_groups.htm